# jQuery HTML - mobile device: onclick not working as long as input is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got questionaire like:

```
Question1 <textarea id="answer1"></textarea></td>
Question2 <textarea id="answer2"></textarea></td>
```

etc. it goes till 50 and then:

```
<a onclick="fragebogen()">save</a>
```

The problem is that when `input` like `answer33` is still active and the user click on `save` then `fragebogen()` won't be called but instead `answer33` is just becoming non active. It's hard to notice that to click on `save` again.

How could I solve the problem? I hope the problem is good explained ^^

Comment: try to change that to a button...

`<button onclick="fragebogen()" value="save" />`

A follo up question, how do you know it is not called? do you have at least one `console log` to ensure the code is not hit?

Comment: it's the same with button I already tried. Dude because the questionaire isn't getting saved? xD Only after clicking on save the second time, on first time the screen goes to the textarea which was active. I hate smartphones -_-

Comment: I can't reproduce this, can you provide a live example?

Comment: Chris did you tried it with chrome on mobile phone? I just checked that it only happens when the textarea which is active is out of the screen. so when it's like the last question which is right by "save" then it's getting saved on first click. so the active textarea must be out of the screen. sry for my bad english -_-

Comment: I was able to reproduce it; it looks like the onscreen keyboard is intercepting the click. When I'm in the middle of typing a word and getting suggestions from the keyboard, then scroll down and click save, the click doesn't work. When I end with a space or return (i.e. no suggestions are displayed), the click registers the first time. Not sure there's a fix for this.

Comment: That's a nice find with the space at the end, it rly work's with that. Wth should I do now, damn smartphones I rly hate these things for degenerates -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution: use the `ontouchstart` event:

```
<a onclick="fragebogen()" ontouchstart="fragebogen()">save</a>
```

Comment: Hmmm ontouchstart don't work for me :( What browser do you use?

Comment: Chrome, Android 6.0.1. I just checked again, and it definitely works.

Comment: I believe you maybe it's not working for me because my phone and the chrome/android version isn't that new. It wouldn't be a problem when everyone got the newest stuff but that's not the case. damn :(

Comment: Try this: http://khrismuc.gmxhome.de/frage.html The "savetouch" should always work.

Comment: It works on second time by me, on first click/touch it just deactivate the textarea which is out of screen and scrolls to it, just like onclick. Maybe adding a space to the active textarea as soon as it's out of screen would do the trick?

Comment: I tested my example page on Chrome on Android 4.1.2 and it worked on the spot. I can consistently reproduce the problem by tapping on "saveclick" (browser scrolls up to out-of-screen textarea) as well as use the fix, tapping on "savetouch" always works on the spot, regardless of keyboard state.

Comment: I just cleared the cache and now it works with ontouchstart xD it just suck to do it every time you have to test something. I HATE smartphones